# jQuery animate nested divs: gecko and webkit differences

Tags: jquery, webkit, jquery-animate

This is a jQuery animation question where I am implementing a sliding effect for elements in my DOM tree.

Somewhere in my code, I have a parent div acting as a sliding tab with other divs nested in it. When a mouse click is detected on a button, the parent div and its content slide into view on the screen, or slides off the screen.

For simplicity, here are snippets.
HTML of the div in question looks this:

```
<div id="parentTab" class="tabby">
    <!-- nested here are other divs -->
    <div id="child1"> </div>
</div>
```

javascript of the animation code:

```
$('#parentTab').animate(
{'left':'-=' +
      ($('#parentTab').width())}, 'slow',
            function() {
                // do something after tab comes into view
            });
```

In my code, I only call jquery's animate() on the parent div. The code works as intended on Firefox. All the nested div slides left/right with the parent div.
But with webkit based browsers such as Safari or Chrome, I run into a problem where the parent div animates correctly, but the nested divs are visually incorrectly positioned, and seems to stop short of where they are supposed to be positioned.
The funny thing is, when I use the Developer tool to examine the HTML elements,the nested divs snap into the correct position within the parent div. So from that perspective, the browser seems to think that the elements are in the correct position, but visually, the elements are not positioned correctly.

Anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use variables for animating values and don't forgot to add `'px'` for internet explorer bug fix.

```
var targetWidth = $('#parentTab').width();

$('#parentTab').animate({'left':'-=' +targetWidth+ 'px'}, 'slow', function() {
      // do something after tab comes into view
});
```